# In Php trying to read a csv file to display in array

Tags: php, yii

I have a csv file with phone column and name column . I want to fetch the phone number as value and name as key .Its a loong file . Here is my code that I tried;

```
   public function actionReadfile(){
      $file=('ContactList.csv'.'r'); 
      if($file==Null){
       return;
    }else{
        
        while (($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
            $file_arr[] = $data;
        }
        foreach($data as $value){
            array_push($value->$file_arr);
            Yii::$app->response->format=Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return $file_arr;     
      }
      fclose($file); 
}
```

}

I tried using fgetcsv($file) name of the file but im getting error.'Argument '1' passed to fgetcsv() is expected to be of type resource, string givenPHP(PHP0406)'

Comment: $file=('ContactList.csv'.'r');  ... was that supposed to involve fopen?

Comment: You're probably better off using the number as the key, since that has to be unique. The proposed design will break if you get two numbers for one person, or two people with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because `fgetcsv` requires an opened file, to be parsed.
Cf: [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Your code will look better this way:

```php
public function actionReadfile() {
    $file = fopen("ContactList.csv", "r");
    if (false === $file) {
        return;
    }
    
    while (($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
        //... bla bla bla
    }
    fclose($file); 
}
```